# Boundary conditions and uniqueness of heat equation solution

Tags: thermodynamics, boundary-conditions

I have some confusion about the uniqueness of solution in an unstable heat transfer problem. The domain of this problem is shown in the figure below, which is infinite in the left-right direction, where temparature at the upper boundary $\scriptsize W_1 W_2 W_3 W_4 W_5W_6$ and lower boundary (lower straight line shown in the figure) is given. The initial temparature distribution in the whole domain is also known.

[image]

In order to have a unique solution (temprature distribution in the whole doamin), do I still need temprature distribution at the left and right infinite boundaries?

Comment: I think you just have to impose that the temperature tends to zero as $x-> \infty$ and $x->-\infty$. This is what is normally considered in this type of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you still need a boundary condition. But, bear in mind there are *two* types of boundary conditions possible. You can specify a [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) boundary condition by imposing a temperature value along the surface. Or, you can specify a [Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) boundary condition by specifying the derivative of the variable along a boundary. You can, of course, have mixed boundaries if you have multiple variables and you can have sections of a boundary be Neumann and sections be Dirichlet, if that is what is required.

So -- you will need to impose a boundary condition for all of your boundaries. I will leave it to you to decide the most appropriate one(s) in this case.

Comment: Hi, @tpg2114, thanks for your help. But I missed an important point and made a little change to this problem, could you please take a look again. I forget to mention that it's unstable.

Comment: @David I don't know that being unstable changes anything. If a unique solution exists, you must have both initial and boundary conditions for all boundaries. Otherwise the problem is ill-posed. What type (Neumann/Dirichlet/Mixed) and what values you give them determines which of the unique solutions you get. So you will always need boundary conditions on all boundaries.